# how do fix "uninitialized constant Context::DateTime" error?

Tags: ruby, datetime

I am running into a uninitialized constant Context::DateTime error in Ruby. My code is:

```
# Print data about a list of Tweets
def print_timeline(tweets)
  tweets.each do |tweet|
    d = datetime.new(tweet['created_at'])
    puts "#{tweet['user']['name']} , #{tweet['text']} , #{d.strftime('%m.%d.%y')} , #{tweet['id']}"
  end
end
```

I believe it is saying it cannot find the DateTime class, and I am not sure why. I am new to Ruby.

Answer (score 6):

`DateTime` should be capitalized, just like in the title of your question. Also you may have to add a:

```
require "date"
```

Comment: After changing the DateTime and adding require 'date' above d.DateTime....., I am now running into a "comparison of String with 0 failed" error.

Comment: this error is in another part of the code. You have no comparison at all in the call above. Please avoid adding unrelated questions in comments to a question that is already answered.